# How do I prevent pdfpages from either rescaling or cropping the included PDF?

Tags: pdfpages

Assume I have two PDFs that I want to stitch together. Both have the same width (standard A4), but one of them is much higher (page height adjusted by using the `geometry` package).

Now, when I include the bigger PDF within the smaller, it gets either rescaled or cropped, depending on whether I have rescaling turned on in the `pdfpages` command. I want neither of this to happen – I simply want to have them stitched together in their original dimensions. How do I do this?

**Small.tex** (and **Small.pdf**)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
Page \#1 of small document.
\newpage
\includepdf[noautoscale]{Big.pdf}
\end{document}
```

**Big.tex** (and **Big.pdf**)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, paperheight=30in, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
Page \#1 of big document.\\

\blindtext[20]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Most probably you need `\newgeometry` command (`geometry`) package to resize the margins etc. for the larger one.

Comment: I treid `\newgeometry{paperheight=20in}` before `\includepdf`, but it didn't help. The included PDF either gets rescaled to standard A4 dimensions (the dimensions of my original document), or cropped if `noautoscale` is used.

Comment: You should show us how the separate files are generated and how you want to combine them.

Comment: You are not expecting a 30in paperheight document fitting into A4 format height (which is about 30cm, or 12in), are you?

Comment: I am not. I am expecting to have the two stitched together, i.e. one page of A4, then the big one, then again A4.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `pdfpages` provides an options to do just that which is switched off by default:

> **fitpaper** Adjusts the paper size to the one of the inserted document.
>   Either 'true' or 'false' (or no value, which is equivalent to 'true').
>   (Default: `fitpaper=false`)

So in your original `Small.tex`, replacing the `noautoscale` option with `fitpaper=true`, will what you are asking:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
Page \#1 of small document.
\newpage
\includepdf[fitpaper=true]{Big.pdf}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot with Adobe Reader]

Comment: Thanks! I should have looked at the docs more carefully.

Answer (score 3):

here is a solution using typearea package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,pagesize]{typearea}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
Page \#1 of small document.
\newpage
\KOMAoptions{paper=21cm:30in,pagesize}
\includepdf[noautoscale]{Big.pdf}
\newpage
\KOMAoptions{paper=a4,pagesize}
\end{document}
```