# How to keep paper size when renumbering pages?

Tags: page-numbering, pdfpages

I'm using Linux `pdflatex` to change the number of pages in a PDF (I want the first pages to use Roman numbers, and the remaining pages, Arabic numbers, so that the PDF pages match the document pages).

That's my first try:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[pdfpagelabels]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\roman{page}}
\includepdf[pages=1-8]{Meeus 1998 Astronomical Algorithms.pdf}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\includepdf[pages=9-]{Meeus 1998 Astronomical Algorithms.pdf}
\end{document}
```

But this converts the page size to a default US Letter (8.50 × 11.00 inch), when the original PDF had the dimensions 5.74 × 9.25 inch (according to Gnome's Evince Document Viewer 3.38.2).

So I tried to tell the correct dimensions:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[paperheight=9.25in,paperwidth=5.74in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[pdfpagelabels]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\roman{page}}
\includepdf[pages=1-8]{Meeus 1998 Astronomical Algorithms.pdf}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\includepdf[pages=9-]{Meeus 1998 Astronomical Algorithms.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Although the result looks much better, it's still not identical. Is there a way to just renumber the PDF, whithout messing with the pages size?

Comment: Quick answer: use `\includepdf[fitpaper, pages=...]{...}`. Similar: [How do I prevent pdfpages from either rescaling or cropping the included PDF?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/234480).

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Thank you, it works! Two more questions: 1) It seems I need to include `fitpaper` in every call to `\includepdf` (in a certain book I had to make several calls, because some white pages were not included). Is this the way to go? 2) It updated the PDF from version 1.4 to 1.5. Don't know if that's the reason, but the size of the paper on screen, under 100% zoom (in Evince), is very different, although both documents show the same paper size (4.62 × 6.93 inch). Is there a way for the final document to show the same (in pixels) on screen too?

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ One more note: the first page was smaller, and it became the same size of the other 15 from the first command (`\includepdf[fitpaper,pages=1-16]{...}`). If I want to keep it different, I have to split it into its own command. Wonder if there's a single command to keep ALL pages in the document the same?

Comment: 1) There's `\includepdfset{<global options>}` 2) Perhaps you can post a new question with a new example. 3) According to options `pagetemplate` and `templatesize`, seems so (you have to split it into several commands).